# MS Access Query with multiple conditions

Tags: sql, ms-access

How to build the following query in MS Access?

**write** down in my results table the following values:

When
Column 1:

- The three rows contain the same number value "####", but the "####" has to be found with all of the 3 extensions  "*.par", "*.dft", "*.psm"

AND Column 2

- The first row in the example must have the same value as in the second row

AND Column 3

- The first row in the example must have the same value as in the second row

| Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234.par | 1234 | 01 |
| 1234.dft | 1234 | 01 |
| 1234.psm | 1234 | 01 |

FYI:
**Not** write in Query following results:

- when are in the table only 1234.par and 1234.dft
  or when are in the table more 1234.par and 1234.dft, but they own different value in Column 3

| Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234.par | 1234 | 01 |
| 1234.dft | 1234 | 01 |
| 1234.par | 1234 | **02** |
| 1234.dft | 1234 | **02** |

Thank you for any tip!

Comment: SQL tables don't have "rows numbers" so what does "row 1" and "row 2" mean?

Comment: Seems like a job for Excel.

Comment: I assume that all three rows must match in Column 2 and Column 3.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a self join to compare rows of the same table. This yields the 3 rows belonging together as one row.

```sql
SELECT t1.Column1, t2.Column1, t3.Column1, t1.Column2, t1.Column3
FROM
    (T AS t1
     INNER JOIN T AS t2 ON (t1.Column3 = t2.Column3) AND (t1.Column2 = t2.Column2))
     INNER JOIN T AS t3 ON (t2.Column3 = t3.Column3) AND (t2.Column2 = t3.Column2)
WHERE
    t1.Column1=[t1].[Column2] & '.par' AND
    t2.Column1=[t2].[Column2] & '.dft' AND
    t3.Column1=[t3].[Column2] & '.psm';
```

If you need them as three rows you have different possibilities. One would be to use this query 3 times in a UNION ALL query by selecting the columns from a different the tables each time:

```sql
SELECT t1.Column1, t1.Column2, t1.Column3
FROM
    (T AS t1
     INNER JOIN T AS t2 ON (t1.Column3 = t2.Column3) AND (t1.Column2 = t2.Column2))
     INNER JOIN T AS t3 ON (t2.Column3 = t3.Column3) AND (t2.Column2 = t3.Column2)
WHERE
    t1.Column1=[t1].[Column2] & '.par' AND
    t2.Column1=[t2].[Column2] & '.dft' AND
    t3.Column1=[t3].[Column2] & '.psm'
UNION ALL
SELECT t2.Column1, t2.Column2, t2.Column3
FROM
    (T AS t1
     INNER JOIN T AS t2 ON (t1.Column3 = t2.Column3) AND (t1.Column2 = t2.Column2))
     INNER JOIN T AS t3 ON (t2.Column3 = t3.Column3) AND (t2.Column2 = t3.Column2)
WHERE
    t1.Column1=[t1].[Column2] & '.par' AND
    t2.Column1=[t2].[Column2] & '.dft' AND
    t3.Column1=[t3].[Column2] & '.psm'
UNION ALL
SELECT t3.Column1, t3.Column2, t3.Column3
FROM
    (T AS t1
     INNER JOIN T AS t2 ON (t1.Column3 = t2.Column3) AND (t1.Column2 = t2.Column2))
     INNER JOIN T AS t3 ON (t2.Column3 = t3.Column3) AND (t2.Column2 = t3.Column2)
WHERE
    t1.Column1=[t1].[Column2] & '.par' AND
    t2.Column1=[t2].[Column2] & '.dft' AND
    t3.Column1=[t3].[Column2] & '.psm'
```

Another possibility is to use the first query as a sub-select and to join it to the table itself again:

```sql
SELECT T.*
FROM
   (SELECT t1.Column1 as C1, t2.Column1 as C2, t3.Column1 as C3, t1.Column2, t1.Column3
    FROM
        (T AS t1
         INNER JOIN T AS t2 ON (t1.Column3 = t2.Column3) AND (t1.Column2 = t2.Column2))
         INNER JOIN T AS t3 ON (t2.Column3 = t3.Column3) AND (t2.Column2 = t3.Column2)
    WHERE
        t1.Column1=[t1].[Column2] & '.par' AND
        t2.Column1=[t2].[Column2] & '.dft' AND
        t3.Column1=[t3].[Column2] & '.psm') AS X
    INNER JOIN T ON (X.C1 = T.Column1 OR X.C2 = T.Column1 OR X.C3 = T.Column1);
```

Note that the last two examples cannot be displayed in the visual query designer. You must use the SQL view of the designer. Also, the visual query designer tends to deform the last query and render it unusable.